# mysql join two tables with null value

Tags: mysql

Im struggling to join two tables that might output some null value

here is my 1st table named: Leave_Type

```
id  name            days_entitled
1   Vacation leave   12
2   Sick leave       12
3   maternity leave  5
4   paternity leave  5
```

Leave Details

```
requester_id requester_name leave_type_id   days_consumed
1            John           1               1   
1            John           2               3
1            John           1               1
```

Id like to see the result for requester John

```
id  name            days_entitled   days_consumed
1   Vacation leave   12             2
2   Sick leave       12             3
3   maternity leave  5              0
4   paternity leave  5              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result as

```
select 
lt.*,
coalesce(x.days_consumed,0) as days_consumed
from leave_type lt 
left join ( 
  select leave_type_id, 
  sum(days_consumed) as days_consumed 
  from leave_details 
  where requester_id = 1 group by leave_type_id
)x on x.leave_type_id = lt.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to using `left join`

```
select id,name,days_entitled, ifNull(days_consumed,0) from
Leave_Type left outer join Leave_Details on leave_type_id = id
```

Comment: i can get the same value if I filter the query (where requester_id=1)

Comment: what if John has two entry of same leave type like 2 ?

Comment: @Keval Then OP have to use `group by` and `sum` function. But it is not ask in the question as i can see.

Answer (score 0):

Great.

```
select `requester`, tbl_hr_leave_type.id,name,`days_entitled`,sum(days) as Credit from
tbl_hr_leave_type left outer join tbl_hr_leave_form on tbl_hr_leave_form.`leave_details` = tbl_hr_leave_type.id and requester='411'
group by name
order by tbl_hr_leave_type.id
```